# I am not pretty sure about what to do" what does PRETTY exact meaning out here?

Tags: meaning

"I am not pretty sure about what to do" what does PRETTY exact meaning out here?

What places we can use it?

Comment: Here 'pretty' is used the same as 'very' or 'quite' or 'really'.

Comment: Have you read this? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125910/when-and-how-did-pretty-enter-english-as-an-intensifying-adverb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word 'pretty', as a degree modifier, is not used with regular negative statements.

> "I am pretty sure what to do." [here, pretty = 'well on the way to
>   being']
>
> *"I am not pretty sure (about) what to do."

One could contrive a sentence containing a quote which would license it:

> Joe: "John's pretty sure about what to do."
>
> John: *"No, I am not 'pretty sure about what to do'."

Comment: Or "I'm not *pretty* sure about what to do, I am entirely sure about what to do."

Comment: Two could contrive a sentence containing a quote which would license it.